# How to enable OAuth in TAM ESSO

Tags: oauth-2.0, tivoli, tivoli-identity-manager

How to configure OAuth2.0 endpoint url in Tivoli Access Manager for Enterprise Single Sign-On. Any help on this will be really helpful.